# Why default controller and action aren't visible at URI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

When we run an ASP.NET MVC application, at the very first time, we can't see at the URI the default route. I mean, actually we are going to the properly action and the view is being rendered well. But I can't see the at my URI the controller neither the action.

Let's say the my route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Everething works fine, but at my URI I just can see:

```
http://localhost:25346/
```

I would like to see the full path, like that:

```
http://localhost:25346/Home/Index/
```

Comment: That's the whole point of the default route.  If such a thing didn't exist, how would MVC figure out what to display when you navigate to `http://localhost:25346/`?

Comment: In my default route I have some values like: http://localhost:25346/Home/Index/2013/9/1 and I want to be able to grab these values in my view using something like: ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Year"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the site loads, it looks at the url, and tries to match the incoming url using the Route Engine.

```
url/dummycontroller/dummyaction
```

If you have a controller which is caller `Dummy`, and this has an Action `DummyAction`, then this will map - otherwise fail.  If you just put in `URL`, then there is no `Controller` or `Action` to look for, therefore, it uses the default which in your case is `Home/Index`.

If you want to add a new route, you can do so, but remember to add the more specific routes `before` the default.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking way too difficult, let MVC use its 'magic' and do the work for you. According to your comment you probably want a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "IndexWithDate",
    url: "Home/Index/{year}/{month}/{day}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Now create an an action in your `HomeController`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int year, int month, int day)
{
    ViewBag.Year = year;
    ViewBag.Month = month;
    ViewBag.Day = day;

    return View();      
}
```

Now with an url like `localhost:25346/Home/Index/2013/9/1`, your parameters in the action will be filled. `year` = 2013, `month` = 9 and `day` = 1. You could place these values in the `ViewBag` (see above) or create a ViewModel so you can use them in your view.